# How to cancel a Paypal Billing Agreement without the ID?

Tags: php, curl, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions

I'm using the Paypal rest API. My system process work like this.

```
1) Create a Billing plan.
2) Activate the Billing plan.
3) Create a Billing Agreement.
```

The user are redirected to the approval page. The user can either approve or cancel the agreement.

[image]
If the user approves the Billing agreement it will be redirected to our execute agreement page and if cancel, it will be redirected to our cancel agreement page.

If the user approves it will be redirected to our executeAgreement page, and using the PaymentToken I can execute it. (using curl)

If the user click the "Cancel and return to test" please see the image.

It will be redirected to our cancelAgreement page. The problem is in order to cancel an agreement, I need the Billing Agreement id, which is not present upon creation. I thought PaymentToken will work, but it don't.

```
Array
(
    [name] => INVALID_PROFILE_ID
    [message] => The profile ID is invalid
    [information_link] => https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments.billing-agreements#errors
    [debug_id] => a2162a5e35584
)
```

Comment: If there is no payment done, which ID should be submitted?

Comment: I need the id of the Billing Agreement to track it in my database. You can only get the id if the customer approves the agreement and then execute the Billing Agreement.

Comment: @NicoHaase the customer have 2 choices. Approves or Cancel, if the customer approves the agreement then he will be redirected to the execute page, using the payment token the Billing Agreement is then executed. If the customer cancel, then he is redirected to cancel page, although the PaymentToken exist on redirect, you cannot use it to cancel the agreement.